# Catch Except for request with SSL Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I send a HEAD request to `expired.badssl.com` in order to test how the script will respond, I get the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='expired.badssl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

Can I specifically catch the `SSLError` so that I know it's a bad SSL?

I need to assign this part to a variable in the `except`: `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` from `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)`

My request:

```
host = "https://expired.badssl.com/"
timeout = 5

try:
    r = requests.head(host, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)

    try:
        print ('Status', r.status_code)
        print ('Headers', r.headers)

    except NameError:
        print("Undefined variable")

except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print ('Timeout...')

except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    print ('Bad URL...')

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print (e)
```

Comment: Have you tried catching `requests.exceptions.SSLError` ?

Comment: @EdWard I tried. It returns the same: `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='revoked.badssl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))`

Comment: Wha do you mean by this?  I need to assign this part to a variable in the except: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED from [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex From the `e` I want to extract the actual reason why the SSL failed. This in particular: `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`, `DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL` or whatever else the error is. It's inside here `[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it via the exceptions arguments:

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.head("https://expired.badssl.com/", timeout=5)

    try:
        print ('Status', r.status_code)
        print ('Headers', r.headers)

    except NameError:
        print("Undefined variable")

except requests.exceptions.SSLError as ssl_error:
    print(ssl_error)
    inner_exception = ssl_error.args[0]
    inner_ssl_error = inner_exception.reason.args[0]
    print(type(inner_ssl_error))
    for key, value in vars(inner_ssl_error).items():
        print(key, '=', value)
    # or just inner_ssl_error.reason etc.
```

Comment: Can I extract `DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL` from `[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:852)` in `print( e.args[0].reason )`

Comment: @Borsn edited my answer, it `DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL` should be in `inner_ssl_error.reason`

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I plan to use this answer to improve my own exception handling code.

Comment: @ChristopherKrause It is inside `reason`. However I need the extracted `DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL` out of  `[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:852)`.

Comment: @Borsn I'm getting `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1076)` as the error and for me `inner_ssl_error.reason` returns `'CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED'`. Did you try my updated code?

Comment: @ChristopherKrause Yeah I missed something. Thank you, works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

test below code

```
import requests 

host = "https://expired.badssl.com/";
timeout = 5
try:
    r = requests.head(host)


    try:
        print ('Status', r.status_code)
        print ('Headers', r.headers)

    except NameError:
        print("Undefined variable")
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print ('Timeout...')
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    print ('Bad URL...')
except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
    print('certificate verify failed')
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print (e)
```

OR

```
import requests
class check_link:
  def check_broken_link(self,data):
    try:
      r = requests.head(data)                 
      try:
                print ('Status', r.status_code)
                print ('Headers', r.headers)

      except NameError:
          return ("UNDEFINED")

    except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
        return "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"

qc=check_link()
result =qc.check_broken_link('https://expired.badssl.com/')
print(result)
```

Comment: Right. But I need the errors it actually returns, like: `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` from `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)`.